# How do I load input from API data and submit with validation from React State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have an API that provides input type(text, radio, or DateTime, dropdown). and we show the input field or dropdown input field according to attriput_code. input type may be different according to the attribute frontend_input type.

**Now I wanna get all types of fields, and change values in form submission.**

```
{attributes?.map(subOption => {
              switch (subOption?.frontend_input) {
                case 'text':
                  return
                  <Controller
                    name={subOption.attribute_code}
                    control={control}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <TextField
                        {...field}
                        className="mt-8 mb-16"
                        error={!!errors.subOption.attribute_code}
                        required
                        label="Tax Excluded Price"
                        helperText={errors?.subOption?.attribute_code?.message}

                        autoFocus
                        id={subOption.attribute_code}
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                      />
                    )}
                  />;
                case 'select':
                  return (
                    <>
                      <Controller
                        name={subOption.attribute_code}
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                          <Select
                            className="mt-8 mb-16"
                            labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
                            id={subOption.attribute_code}
                            value=""
                            label={subOption.default_frontend_label}
                            style={{ margin: "10px 0px" }}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            fullWidth
                          >
                            <MenuItem key="" value="" selected >
                              {subOption?.default_frontend_label}
                            </MenuItem>
                            {subOption?.options?.map(selectOption => {
                              return (
                                <MenuItem key={selectOption?.value} value={selectOption?.value}>
                                  {selectOption?.label}
                                </MenuItem>
                              );
                            })}
                          </Select>
                        )}
                      />
                    </>
                  )
                case 'date':
                  return (
                    <>
                      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                        <DatePicker
                          name={subOption.attribute_code}
                          className="mt-8 mb-16"
                          label="Basic example"
                          value="2022-10-10"
                          onChange={(newValue) => {
                            setValue(newValue);
                          }}
                          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                          fullWidth
                        />
                      </LocalizationProvider>
                    </>
                  )
               
                default:
                  return (
                    <><h1>not found</h1></>
                  )
              }
            })}
```

For Specific input field types and names(Like watch('name')), we have only the below code.

```
  const { formState, watch, getValues } = methods;
  const name = watch('name');
  function handleSaveProduct() {
    console.log("Form Submit Vlaue");
    console.log(getValues());
    dispatch(saveProduct(getValues()));
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @timotgl I just wanna call the API. Populated the field text and dropdown field and get data from that field and call API in from submit.

my difficulty is that I cannot take on change value from those dynamic fields.

Thank you advance

Comment: Have you tried creating a new object from `getValues()` before you dispatch the action?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to save the inputs dynamically created in a Array of objects, like this:

```
   const initialStateArray = [{
            title: '', listid: 1, name: 'title'
        },
        {
            subtitle: '', listid: 2, name: 'subtitle'
        },
        {
            embed: '', listid: 3, name: 'embed'
        },
        {
            cover: '', listid: 4, name: 'cover'
        },
        {
            category: '0', listid: 5, name: 'category'
        }]

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialStateArray);
```

In this example, `listid` is custom attribute i made to be able to update the value with the `onChange` method.

Now you map through the state, which in this example is `formData`. So everytime you update the value, the form will rerender and keep it synced.

Your input with the custom attributte will be something like this:

```
<div className={Style.inputContainer} key={3} listid={3}>
      <label htmlFor="embed">Embed Link</label>
      <input onChange={handleInputChange} type="text" name="embed" placeholder='#'  />
</div>
```

For your input change, do this:

```
function handleInputChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const listid = parseInt(e.target.parentNode.attributes.listid.value)
        
        setFormData(prevState => (
            prevState.map(input => {

                if (input.listid === listid) {
                    input[name] = value
                }
                return input
            })
        ));
        
    }
```

The function does the following:

- Grab the name and value of the input changed
- Search on the input tree for the custom attributed
- Updates the state of the formData

This will vary depending on the structure of the object used for the creation of the inputs, but thats the idea.

If you need to add inputs after the user interaction, you can create a function that updates the object keys while preserving the state of the values. Like this:

```
function handleInputAdd(info) {

        const { name, title, type } = info;

        if (type === 'gallery') {
            setFormData([...formData, { gallery: [], listid: inputId, name: name, title: title, type: type }]);

        } else {
            setFormData([...formData, { [name]: '', listid: inputId, name: name, title: title, type: type }]);
        }

    }
```